# Can't reverse the legend of tm_bubbles

Tags: r

I created a dot map with that code

```
map = st_as_sf(map)




tm_shape(map) + tm_fill("ratio",style = "cont")
```

I also tried function rev() but nothing work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `legend.col.reverse`. See `help(tm_bubbles)` for all the legend reversal arguments - I don't see a `legend.reverse` in my version:

```
   legend.size.reverse = FALSE,
   legend.col.reverse = FALSE,
   legend.shape.reverse = FALSE,
```

Example using `nc` as ever:

```
tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74") +  tm_bubbles(col="SID79", legend.col.reverse=FALSE, style="order")
```

[image]

```
tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74") +  tm_bubbles(col="SID79", legend.col.reverse=TRUE, style="order")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `legend.col.reverse = TRUE` in `tm_bubbles(col = "SSEP",scale = 0.45,style="order")`

Reproducible example:

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

data(World, metro)
metro$growth <- (metro$pop2020 - metro$pop2010) / (metro$pop2010 * 10) * 100

tm_shape(World) +
    tm_fill("grey70") +
    tm_shape(metro) +
    tm_bubbles("pop2010", col = "growth", 
               border.col = "black", border.alpha = .5, 
               style="fixed", breaks=c(-Inf, seq(0, 6, by=2), Inf),
               palette="-RdYlBu", contrast=1, 
               title.size="Metro population", 
               title.col="Growth rate (%)",   legend.col.reverse = TRUE) + 
    tm_format("World")
```